# Edição de XML: Como eu posso obter o valor de uma propriedade

Tags: c#

Tô com uma dúvida pra ler e editar um XML em C Sharp. Eu preciso obter o valor do atributo "uuid" do nó "Machine", este que está no nó "Virtualbox". Eu também quero as propriedades "location" e "uuid" de cada um dos nós de "HardDisk", como na imagem. [Aqui está o link do arquivo XML](http://1drv.ms/1Hnwma5)

[image: Propriedades desejadas]

Eu fiz esse código com a ajuda do usuário **psNytrancez**. Pegar o `uuid` de `Machine` funciona, mas para ir a um nível mais baixo, em `HardDisk´, eu não consegui resultado.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"Z:\Área de Trabalho\Windows XP.xml");
var no = doc.Root.Element("Machine");
foreach (var elemento in doc.Root.Elements())
{
    if (elemento.Name.LocalName == "Machine")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Anterior: -" + elemento.Attribute("uuid").Value + "-");
        break;
        // Essa parte funciona perfeitamente.
    }
}

foreach (var elemento in doc.Root.Elements())
{
    if (elemento.Name.LocalName == "HardDisk")
    {
        Console.Write("-" + elemento.Attribute("uuid").Value + "-");
        Console.WriteLine("-" + elemento.Attribute("location").Value + "-");
        //Mas esta não lista nenhum resultado, sendo que tem dois no arquivo XML
    }
}
```

O mais interessante pra mim é um for ou foreach pra percorrer cada um dos sub nós de `HardDisks`, assim não importa o número de nós.

Valeu gente.

Comment: Pode por favor substituir o XML da imagem por texto? Gostaria de fazer uns testes aqui.

Comment: Coloquei uma resposta, mas para eu conseguir garantir que ela vai funcionar favor colocar o xml completo.

Comment: Valeu mesmo. Seu código funcionou certinho, mas agora eu tenho um problema diferente. Eu complementei minha pergunta, Agora eu preciso pegar o valor de um nó de um nível mais baixo e minha adaptação do que você me passou não funciona nesse caso.Abre o link do XML, o arquivo agora é outro mas tem a mesma estrutura

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var valorUuid = "";
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"Z:\Área de Trabalho\Windows Vista.xml");
var machine = doc.Root.Element("Machine");
foreach (var element in doc.Root.Elements())
{
   if (element.Name.LocalName == "Machine") 
   {
       valorUuid = element.Attribute("uuid").Value;
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Deu erro `O membro 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(string)' não pode ser acessado com uma referência de instância; qualifique-o com o nome do tipo`. O link do XML é [esse](http://1drv.ms/1G9IquI)

Comment: @MarceloNascimento agora está funcionando!